# System.loadLibrary() error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I successfully cross-compiled a c++ library with the android ndk-Standalone toolchain
then, i created a new android application project into Eclipse and when i put mylib.so into the jni folder and execute ndk-build commands it works fine

```
Prebuilt       : mylib.so <= jni/
Install        : mylib.so => libs/armeabi/mylib.so
```

But when adding

```
static{
  System.load("/data/data/my_package/lib/mylib.so");
}
```

i got an error in the logcat saying

```
   AndroidRuntime
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
   reloc_library[1306]:      36 cannot locate 'xmlCleanupParser'...``
```

i googled it but didn't find any way to solve this problem.

Comment: you should not provide full path of the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently encountered the same error. After trying out dozens of suggestions from SO, I finally figured out that the **error was in my native code.** even though android **ndk had compiled it without any issues / warnings.**

Try writing a simple main function to test your native code and compile with g++/gcc (or something similar) to check for errors.

I know its too late for the asker, but hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: that was the problem.

Answer (score 11):

People mostly forgot cut "lib" prefix form library name. So if you have "libusb.so" your code must be System.loadLibrary("usb")...

Answer (score 5):

If you have your compiled native library (the `.so`-file) in your `lib/`-directory, you can refer to it without using the full path:

```
static{
  System.load("mylib");
}
```

As shown in the [tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html).

---

Check to see if you set the right package in your Header-file: [How to resolve the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in NDK in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262440/how-to-resolve-the-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-ndk-in-android)

Comment: I tried static { System.loadLibrary("mylib"); } But i got the error

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
       System.load("/data/data/<package name>/lib/libsample-jni.so");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       System.loadLibrary("<sample-jni>"); //remove lib and .so from name
}
```

this will help you, Pls. check.

Answer (score 2):

Please specify your .so file like as follow.

```
 static {

     System.loadLibrary("mylib");

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried 
    static {

      System.loadLibrary("mylib");

    }
But i got the error

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
    LOCAL_MODULE := dash
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libdash.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)