# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError Android

Tags: java, android, loadlibrary

I am using follow code in android.

```
System.loadLibrary("openal");
```

When Running the application it gives run time error as below.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load openal from loader 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.MoNTE48.MultiCraft-
1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.MoNTE48.MultiCraft-1,
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Why is that error occurs? How to fix it?

Comment: Why minus? What is error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your library in libs\armeabi\ folder. Possible library name should be "libopenal.so" .

Comment: The libraries dowloaded from internet inside application and extract it. So What is error.

Comment: In which folder do you extract libraries?
See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26380738/915194) .

Comment: Do I need to give full path instead of "openal". Which folder do I need to extract te files?

Comment: /data/data/your.package.name/lib . ContextWrapper.getFilesDir() will return the path /data/data/your.package.name so that you don't hardcode it.