# Samsung SPen SDK demo immediately crashes

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

I try to work with the Samsung SPen SDK (http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-3-Tutorial), but as soon as I use anything from it my emulator crashes instantly. Also the SDK-Demo doesn't work on the emulator - it starts up, but as soon as I choose one of the demos from the listview, I directly get an force-close.

Data of the emulator:

- Device: Nexus 7
- Android 4.3 Api Level 18
- Intel Atom (x86)
- Memory:

  - Ram: 1024
  - VM-Heap: 32
- Internal Storage: 200 MB
- Use host GPU: true

For simple code-changes I don't want to need to get the device every time. Is there a 'trick' to get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
As requested here follows the stacktrace of logcat when the error happens

> 10-19 14:27:55.473: D/dalvikvm(2001): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0032
>
> 10-19 14:27:55.493: E/SDraw(2001): This engine isn't supported to run on this device. (brand : generic_x86, manufacturer : unknown)
>
> 10-19 14:27:55.563: E/CB::BeautifyNative(2001): WARNING: Could not load libjni_secime natives

**Update 2:**
When I use the Emulator Library and try to open the SPenGestureLibrary i get the following stacktrace. I have as "code":

```
public MainActivity extends ActivityWithSPenLayer
```

and I use `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` in the overriden method.

```
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load SPenGesture from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testappforgesturelibrary-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testappforgesturelibrary-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.samsung.spen.engine.gesture.SPenGestureEngineJni.<init>(SourceFile:7)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.samsung.spen.engine.gesture.a.a(SourceFile:61)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.samsung.spen.lib.gesture.SPenGestureLibrary.openSPenGestureEngine(SourceFile:122)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.example.testappforgesturelibrary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-19 14:40:10.574: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the "S Pen Emulator Library"?
http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/Testing-S-Pen-apps-on-the-Emulator

Comment: Please see my update in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should NOT use x86 image ...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13870576/1643188

Comment: Well - I'll give it a try with an "usual" AVD, but than it might be faster to go to the office to test on the device instead of starting the emulator...

Comment: It's working when using a non-x86-image, but than the emulator is almost non-usable...

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as @DieselPower commented the "solution" - thanks!