# Gradle doesn't build external project

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle doesn't seem to be building a project I am including:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting, PID: 14678 
     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/libtango_device2.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libcpp_plane_fitting_example.so"
```

In my main `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':cpp_example_util')
}
```

My top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The `build.gradle` of my external project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

def external_lib_prefix = null
if (project.hasProperty("Tango.catkin_devel_prefix")) {
    external_lib_prefix = project.property("Tango.catkin_devel_prefix")
}
```

The `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
include ':cpp_example_util'
project(':cpp_example_util').projectDir = new File('../cpp_example_util/app')
```

As shown in the error, there is no `libcpp_plane_fitting_example` library being built.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error reads `couldn't find "libcpp_plane_fitting_example.so"`, it looks like there is some error with your NDK configuration, which might be why it is not being able to access the native code.

To take care of **UnsatisfiedLinkError**, use

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("yourlibraryname");
}
```

and make sure that the package signature is correct.

Comment: More info on UnsatisfiedLinkError : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262440/how-to-resolve-the-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-ndk-in-android

Comment: `System.loadLibrary("yourlibraryname");` is causing the issue, as it's trying to load a library it can't find. I figured out that it can't find that library because it's not being built, but I can't figure out why it's not being built (project cpp_example_util)